# Why some MAX 10 chips don't support ADC while the datasheet says they do?

Tags: fpga, adc, intel-fpga, max10

I'm using an Altera MAX 10 chip 10M50SCE144C8G. I want to use its ADC. In datasheet, it says that this chip has a "Single ADC that supports 1 dedicated analog input pin and 8 dual-function pins". However, when I want to use it in Quartus, in the IP parameter Editor, I got an error msg saying that:

> Error: unnamed.modular_adc_0: The selected device part number 10M50SCE144C8G does not support ADC.

I tried different versions of Quartus: 15.1 and 16.0, got the same error.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: I honestly think this should be raised with Altera, not with us.

Comment: Its probably a bug, its amazing that Altera even has as much stuff working as they do because not only do they have to spend time fixing software compiler issues, but hardware compiler issues as well. Is this a Qsys or compiler error?

Comment: To be fair this is not a badly written question and doesn't deserve to be downvoted to oblivion.

Answer (score 1):

That part does not support ADC functionally. Page 4 of the [device overview](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/max-10/m10_overview.pdf) specifically states that SC parts are the compact functionality cores which do not feature ADCs. Only the SA and DA parts have analogue features.